# Automatic vertex group assignation

Tags: python, constraints

I'm stuck doing an automatization script that allows me to assign a different vertex group per each constraint. Let me explain:

My scene has 578 Empties with a Transformation constraint

[image]

¿Noticed I have randomly selected Empty.003?
If I check its constraint settings I can see its subtarget is vertex group 'groupy.003' from another object named Template.001

[image]

I have manually assigned that vertex group. Sadly, the 577 other empties have all assigned the same vertex group.
Changing all of them one by one will take ages and will drive me crazy.
What I am looking for is an script that takes every empty from that collection ('empties') and have assigned their corresponding vertex group. For example:

Empty > groupy.000
Empty.001 > groupy.001
Empty.002 > groupy.002
...and so on until
Empty.577 > groupy.577

My crappy Python knowledge only gets too write a variable that includes all of the empties I want to change, but that is all I can do.
I have no idea how to continue. Any help?

import bpy

cons =  bpy.data.collections['empties'].objects

Comment: The code is not entirely present in the question.

Comment: Because that is all I have.

Comment: OK, I think I’m getting more of the idea. You duplicated the empties after setting up the constrained, and all their constraints point of the same vertex group?

Comment: You are right for the part where all of the constraints point to the same vertex group, but I didn't duplicated the empties after setting up the contraints.

Comment: Okay, well, I assume that empty.004 should be constrained to group.004, and so on?

Comment: Yep, that's the idea. I'm either looking for an script that allows me to change the subtarget for every constraint or an script that kills all of the constraints I did and creates new ones to the correct subtarget